# Fix formatting of && operator with sed

Tags: linux, sed, and-operator

I am trying to write a sed command that adds one space to either side of the && (AND) operator. This is what I have so far:

```
sed -E 's+(\&\&)|(\s*\&\&\s*)+ & +g test.c
```

The first condition of no spaces around the && works, so

```
if(numberIn==0&&char=='g')
```

becomes

```
if(numberIn==0 && char=='g')
```

But the second condition of 1 or more spaces doesn't work. So this

```
if(numberIn==0  &&   char=='g')
```

doesn't change.

The pattern of `\s*OPERATOR\s*` worked with other binary operators so I'm not sure why it's not working on the and operator. Am I missing something about using sed on the and operator? With the first condition, I noticed that if you replace it with " && " you actually get " && &&" so that's why the substitute pattern is " & ". (This wasn't the case with the OR or EQUALS operators).

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` in a sed replacement means "insert the matched string".

Use `\&` to insert a literal ampersand:

```
$ echo 'foo   && bar' | sed -E 's+(\&\&)|(\s*\&\&\s*)+ \&\& +g'
foo && bar
```

PS: Get a real code formatted like clang-format.

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to figure this out for two days! None of the other operators need the \ on the replacement. I knew I was missing something about the & operator.

Comment: None of the other operators required escaping in the replacement text because they aren't backreference metacharacters. You don't need to escape `&` in a regexp, it's just a literal character, and `\s*&&\s*` matches `&&` so you don't need to `or` it and so you don't need an ERE. All you need is `sed 's/\s*&&\s*/ \&\& /g'` (still requires GNU sed for `\s` - use `[[:space:]]` instead in any sed).